# How to determine if an image contains a specific color using?

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I need to determine if an image contains a specific color:

```
r:255
g:0
b:192
```

I found this, but instead of returning points, I need to return a Boolean value if the image contains the above color.

```
public static List<Point> FindAllPixelLocations(this Bitmap img, Color color)
        {
            var points = new List<Point>();

            int c = color.ToArgb();

            for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
                {
                    if (c.Equals(img.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb())) points.Add(new Point(x, y));
                }
            }

            return points;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to replace

```
if (c.Equals(img.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb())) points.Add(new Point(x, y));
```

by

```
if (c.Equals(img.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb())) return true;
```

Comment: you might want to chage type of the function to bool so you do not end up checking list.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
    public static bool HasColor(this Bitmap img, Color color)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < img.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < img.Height; y++)
            {
                if (img.GetPixel(x, y) == color)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly both answers are true,but you must know that  `GetPixel(x, y)` and `SetPixel(x, y)` color are very slow,and for an image with a high resolution is not good.

for this you can use `LockBitmap` class here:[Work with bitmaps faster](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp)

this is about 5 time faster.